# Row by row multiplication on pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have one dataframe with classes and two components and a second one with elements and the same components.

df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Class':['banana', 'apple'], 'comp1':[1, 2], 'comp2':[-5, 4]})
```

df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Element':['K', 'Mg'], 'comp1':[3, -4], 'comp2':[1, 3]})
```

I want to multiply them row by row in a way that would generate the following output:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'Class': ['banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple'], 'Element': ['K', 'Mg', 'K', 'Mg'], 'comp1':[3, -4, 6, -8], 'comp2':[-5, -15, 4, 12]})
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your algorithm for multiplying the two dataframes. You seem to do a matrix multiplication on comp1 and comp2 but not sure what you do with Class end Element. Either way it seems that you are applying different algorithm to first row than the other rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well as i see it's like cartesian product. and then some manipulation for desired output as mentioned.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Class':['banana', 'apple'], 'comp1':[1, 2], 'comp2':[-5, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Element':['K', 'Mg'], 'comp1':[3, -4], 'comp2':[1, 3]}) 
#merging data
output  = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')

output['comp1'] = output.pop('comp1_x') * output.pop('comp1_y')
output['comp2'] = output.pop('comp2_x') * output.pop('comp2_y')
print(output)

expected = pd.DataFrame({'Class': ['banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple'], 'Element': ['K', 'Mg', 'K', 'Mg'], 'comp1':[3, -4, 6, -8], 'comp2':[-5, -15, 4, 12]})
print(expected.equals(output)) # True
'''
    Class Element  comp1  comp2
0  banana       K      3     -5
1  banana      Mg     -4    -15
2   apple       K      6      4
3   apple      Mg     -8     12


'''
```

Comment: If OP have multiple comp columns it can be tedious to compute all cols. Can I edit your post to enhanced a small part about `drop`?

Comment: I removed `drop` and use `pop` to get values and delete columns.